# zf2 database driven pages, dynamically processesed from single action

Tags: zend-framework2

How can use single dynamic action for all my database driven (CMS) pages in ZF2?

If an action does not exist it should be served by `dbpageAction()`.

I have following routes (and their associated controller actions) in single controller:

- `/contactus` (contactusAction)
- `/sitemap`   (sitemapAction)
- `/home` (dbpageAction)
- `/aboutus` (dbpageAction)
- `/abcpage` (dbpageAction)

or

Any other db generated page should also be served by `dbpageAction()`

Answer (score 0):

One way could be use of [notFoundAction](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.AbstractActionController.html) in your controller

```
 public function notFoundAction() {
        echo "Action does not exist";
        //Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this could be done. I would use the event manager with the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` event.

The example below is untested; however there is a example [re-dispatching a controller action from within an event listener](https://gist.github.com/weierophinney/3517979) by Matthew Weier O'Phinney.

```
//Module.php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
  $application  = $event->getApplication();
  $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();

  $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function($event) use ($eventManager) {
     $response = $event->getParam('Response');

     // Check the response is a 404
     if (Response::STATUS_CODE_404 === $response->getStatusCode()) {

       // Create a new route match for the target route
       $routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array(
         'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\Foo', // The controller name to use
         'action'     => 'dbPageAction', 
       ));
       // Clone the event and set our new route match
       $newEvent = clone $event;
       $newEvent->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);

       // now dispatch the controller action
       $eventManager->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, $newEvent);

     }
  });
}
```

Keep in mind that should the newly dispatched controller/action also result in a `404` then you might have an infinite loop of not found errors.